# Issue with str_replace replacing the wrong values

Tags: php

I'm trying to replace a list of numbers (ids) with their related title, the problem is that when the title has a number also gets replaced, for example:

```php
$idlist = "1, 2, 3";

$a = array(17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
$b = array('Star Trek 7', 'Superman 8', 'Toy Story 2', 'Terminator 3', 'Other', 'Superman 4', 'Star Trek 3', 'Superman 3', 'Mad Max 3', 'Mad Max 2', 'Superman 3', 'Superman 2', 'Christmas Vacation 3', 'Star Trek 2', 'Terminator 2', 'Toy Story 3', 'Mission Impossible 2');

echo str_replace($a, $b, $idlist);
```

Wrong current result:

```
Mission Impossible 2, Toy Story 3, Terminator Toy Story 3
```

Should be:

```
Mission Impossible 2, Toy Story 3, Terminator 2
```

What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: Build a map whose keys are the movie version and whose values are the text.  Then use the numbers in the first array to lookup in the map.

Comment: This feature's behavior is described in the documentation (*"Because str_replace() replaces left to right, it might replace a previously inserted value when doing multiple replacements."*). Go to [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) manual page and read the notes and code examples. Try another solution, maybe regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `strtr` instead `str_replace`:

```php
$idlist = "1, 2, 3";

$a = array(17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
$b = array('Star Trek 7', 'Superman 8', 'Toy Story 2', 'Terminator 3', 'Other', 'Superman 4', 'Star Trek 3', 'Superman 3', 'Mad Max 3', 'Mad Max 2', 'Superman 3', 'Superman 2', 'Christmas Vacation 3', 'Star Trek 2', 'Terminator 2', 'Toy Story 3', 'Mission Impossible 2');

$pairs = array_combine($a, $b);

echo strtr($idlist, $pairs);
```

Result:

```
Mission Impossible 2, Toy Story 3, Terminator 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gander this solves my problem!

Comment: Now I'm wondering that @mihai-matei 's answer is correct after all. The problem will appear when you get the identifiers in a different order, and it finds the key `12` in the identifier `123`.

Comment: But should be fine If I keep the order from the bigger id to the small id right?

Comment: Should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply combine those 2 arrays and replace the IDs list with [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$array = array_combine($a, $b);

$result = preg_replace_callback('/(\d+)/', static function($matches) use ($array) {
    return $array[$matches[1]];
}, $idlist);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Just a moment ago I realized that you gave a better answer. Your answer should be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating id list like an array of integers:

```
$idlist = array(1, 2, 3);
```

Instead of "1, 2, 3" you can use:

```
array($b[0], $b[1], ... $b[n]).
```

With this form, you can only replace the names in the the array $b, and the names will change in the array list automatically.

Edit:

Convert the string to an array:

```
$ids = explode(",", $idlist);
```

And you can use the array like:

```
$arrayNames = array($b[intval($ids[0])], $b[intval($ids[1])], ... $b[intval($ids[n])]).
```

Comment: The problem is that the id lists are already created, I'm getting those id lists from a database as a string...

Comment: Thanks MR Mark II